# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2+x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, measure-theory

Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2+x} dx$.

Attempt:

Let $h(x)=x^n$. Then $nx^{n-1} = h'(x)$.

I'm thinking about using the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

So $f_n= \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2+x} $.

But I'm not sure what the limit of $f_n$. And I couldn't find any bounds for $f_n$.

So I don't know if DCT will work here.

If DCT doesn't apply here, what would be a good way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The limit is $1/3$, two different approaches to solve: 1) integrate by parts using $nx^{n-1}=(x^n)'$; 2) substitute $x^n=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** you can use the DCT *after* the change of variable.

---

If you want to use the DCT *(it's overkill, but why not?)*: **first**, do the change of variable $u = x^{n}$ you were thinking of. Then,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{n x^{n-1}}{2+x}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2+u^{1/n}}du
$$
and you can now apply the DCT to the **new** integral *(the dominating function being, for instance, $g=1/2$)*. This gives you
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{n x^{n-1}}{2+x}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2+u^{1/n}}du \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{3}du = \frac{1}{3}
$$
since the pointwise limit of $f_n(u)=\frac{1}{2+u^{1/n}}$ on $(0,1]$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand strongly suggest  a gaussian hypergeometric function with a last argument being $\pm \frac x 2$
$$I_n=\int\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+2} dx=\frac{x^n}{2}-\frac{n\, x^{n+1} }{4 (n+1)}\, _2F_1\left(1,n+1;n+2;-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ Assuming $n>1$
$$J_n=\int_0^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+2} dx=\frac 12-\frac n{4(n+1)}\, _2F_1\left(1,n+1;n+2;-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \, _2F_1\left(1,n+1;n+2;-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac 23$$
$$J_n \sim \frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{6 (n+1)}\quad \to\quad \frac 13$$

Answer (score 2):

I think at least one of the suggested ways in metamorphy's comment should appear as answer:

Integration by parts gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2+x}dx
& = & \left.\frac{x^{n}}{2+x}\right|_0^1 + \underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}}{(2+x)^2}dx}_{I_n} \\
& = & \frac 13 + I_n
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, without any dominated convergence you get

$$0\leq I_n \leq \frac 14\int_0^1x^n\;dx = \frac 1{4(n+1)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$